# Using next() on an async generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

A generator can be iterated step by step by using the `next()` built-in function. For example:

```
def sync_gen(n):
    """Simple generator"""
    for i in range(n):
        yield i**2

sg = sync_gen(4)
print(next(sg)) # -> 0
print(next(sg)) # -> 1
print(next(sg)) # -> 4
```

Using `next()` on an asynchronous generator does not work:

```
import asyncio

async def async_gen(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i**2

async def main():
    print("Async for:")
    async for v in async_gen(4):  # works as expected
        print(v)

    print("Async next:")
    ag = async_gen(4)
    v = await next(ag) # raises: TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not an iterator
    print(v)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Does something like `v = await async_next(ag)` exist to obtain same behavior as with normal generators?

Comment: `await iterator.__anext__()`.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448664/async-generator-is-not-an-iterator

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since [Python 3.10 there are `aiter(async_iterable)` and `awaitable anext(async_iterator)` builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#anext), analogous to `iter` and `next`, so you don't have to rely on the `async_iterator.__anext__()` magic method anymore. This piece of code works in python 3.10:

```
import asyncio


async def async_gen(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i**2


async def main():
    print("Async next:")
    ag = async_gen(4)
    print(await anext(ag))


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: That is the answer I was hoping for :-)

Answer (score 8):

As stated `next` will not work on an async generator as it's not an iterator.

If you must use a function you could create a helper function instead of using the `__anext__` function outwrite:

```
async def anext(ait):
    return await ait.__anext__()

ag = async_gen(4)
v = await anext(ag)
print(v)
```

### Edit:

As of python 3.10 they have introduced this as a builtin function: [`anext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#anext)

Comment: since __anext__ already is an awaitable, is it really necessary to add the make the anext def async ?

Answer (score 4):

[PEP525 Asynchronous Generator Object](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#asynchronous-generator-object) describes `__anext__()` method:

> `agen.__anext__()`: Returns an awaitable, that performs one asynchronous generator iteration when awaited.

So it's possible to call it:

```py
print("Async next:")
ag = async_gen(4)
v = await ag.__anext__()
print(v)
```

But as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448664/async-generator-is-not-an-iterator) it is not recommended

Comment: Thanks for the answer including the source. Though I am not sure I understand the reasoning between a generator and iterator in the linked stackoverflow answer.