# How to get the first item of an async generator?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following function.

```
async def f(url):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        async with client.stream('GET', url) as resp:
            async for c in resp.aiter_bytes():
                yield c
```

And I'm writing a test code to test if the function yields.

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test():
    c = None
    async for c in f(URL):
        c = chunk
        break  # there will be no error if removing this line. However, I don't need to loop all the items
    assert c
```

However, the code runs but with the following warnings/errors. What's the error?

> lib\site-packages\httpx_client.py:2012: UserWarning: Unclosed <httpx.AsyncClient object at 0x000001AC1E8CF3A0>. See https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#opening-and-closing-clients for details.

Is the "Unclosed" warning caused by `break`?

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001AC1D884DC0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\s\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\s\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\s\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\s\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

The error disappears if removing the `break` statement.

Comment: No the question doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Try `async with f(URL) as resp: for c in resp: ...`

Comment: It will get the error of `AttributeError: __aexit__` on `async with f(URL) as resp`.

Answer (score 0):

If you break a loop over an async generator, you need to call its `aclose` method to ensure prompt resource cleanup. The warning you got is because you didn't do that. Calling `__anext__` manually, as in the other answer, doesn't solve the problem. `it.__anext__()` doesn't run any of the generator's code or fetch an item from the generator at all; you would need `await it.__anext__()` to do that.

The easiest way to ensure `aclose` is called, even in the face of exceptions, is to use the `contextlib.aclosing` async context manager. Async generator cleanup is even the usage example given in the `contextlib.aclosing` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.aclosing):

```
from contextlib import aclosing

async with aclosing(my_generator()) as values:
    async for value in values:
        if value == 42:
            break
```

For your use case, you would use it like

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test():
    had_elements = False
    async with contextlib.aclosing(f(URL)) as chunks:
        async for c in chunks:
            had_elements = True
            break
    assert had_elements
```

(Also, the `c = chunk` in your original code was buggy, referring to an undefined `chunks` variable. I've fixed that too.)

Answer (score -1):

In the answer of [Async generator is not an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448664/async-generator-is-not-an-iterator), the following code will get rid of the error. However, it needs to call a "special" function `__anext()__()`.

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test():
    it = f(URL):
    c = it.__anext__()
    assert c
```

Comment: I don't want to nitpick, but `__anext__` is a _special_ method, not a _private_ one. There's nothing wrong with using it. Since Python 3.10 you could use `anext(it)` instead (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#anext): "This calls the `__anext__()` method of `async_iterator`").