# TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below piece of code.

```
import asyncio

async def gen_random_numbers():
    for i in range(1, 3):
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        yield [i for i in range(1, 11)]


async def random_processor():
    async for i, numbers in enumerate(gen_random_numbers()):
        print(f"working with the batch {i}  and processing {numbers}")


asyncio.run(random_processor())
```

But this throws an error

```
async for i, numbers in enumerate(gen_random_numbers()):
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
```

One way to fix this is remove the enumerate and keep another variable to keep track of it
and use it.

Is there a way to handle this using enumerate alone ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Async generator is not an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448664/async-generator-is-not-an-iterator)

Comment: Hmm thanks Kris taking a look at that thread but i am still clueless how my problem can be solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [asyncstdlib](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/source/api/builtins.html),

```
import asyncstdlib

async for i, numbers in asyncstdlib.enumerate(gen_random_numbers()):
    print(f"working with the batch {i}  and processing {numbers}")
```

should work.